# C# Windows Phone: Add static PivotItem to databound pivot page

Tags: c#, xaml, pivot, observablecollection, databound

I have a Pivotpage with pivotitems generated from an `ObservableCollection` in my ViewModel.

To make more understandable what i want to do, lets say those items represent folders and the content of the items are the files located in this folder.

What I want to do is to create a static `PivotItem` (as the last element in the pivot control) to create a new folder. This item would have a totally different GUI and thus can not be generated by the same ItemTemplate.

I had the following ideas:

- Adding an additional object with a special key to the `ObservableCollection` and render it somehow different (conditional rendering in my ItemTemplate, but I could not find anything on this topic)
- Add an additional element from code, which does not work for me, because the databound pivot control is read-only
- Add the static item directly in XAML (gets obviously overwritten)

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all your views to your ObservableCollection and use a `TemplateSelector` to chose how it will be displayed.

See here how to implement it:
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/06/multiple-item-templates-in-windows-phone.aspx